# Can I use different Layouts for different Articles

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm developing a Joomla Website using the T3 Framework.
I followed this [article](http://www.t3-framework.org/documentation/layout-system.html#layout-configuration) to duplicate and arrange a second layout.

Is it possible to assign this layout to a specific article or using the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to assign a dynamic layout in the main tamplate file inside "tpls".

Something like this:

```
<?php if(($article_id == 242) || ($article_id == 238) || ($article_id == 234) || ($article_id == 230)): ?>
            <!--/* Slider Comunicações */-->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php $this->_p('slidercommunications') ?>" style="raw" />
        <?php elseif(($article_id == 244) || ($article_id == 240) || ($article_id == 236) || ($article_id == 232)): ?>
            <!--/*  Slider Energias Renováveis*/-->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php $this->_p('sliderrenewableenergies') ?>" style="raw" />
        <?php elseif(($article_id == 243) || ($article_id == 239) || ($article_id == 235) || ($article_id == 231)): ?>
            <!--/* Slider Segurança Electrónica */-->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php $this->_p('sliderelectronicsecurity') ?>" style="raw" />
        <?php elseif(($article_id == 245) || ($article_id == 241) || ($article_id == 237) || ($article_id == 233)): ?>
            <!--/* Slider Aeronáutica */-->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php $this->_p('slideraeronautics') ?>" style="raw" />
        <?php else : ?>
```